# How can i create multiple courier service options in shipping method and price calculated by weight for individual product for both services

Tags: magento-1.9

How can i create multiple courier service options in shipping method and price calculated by weight for individual product for both service.

eg :

- Professional courier [10.2 INR]
- Aramax Courier [12.5 INR]

[image]

Comment: r u using matrix rate ?

Comment: Yes,    I got solution Bro.

Comment: thats grt please post your solution here so that it will help others

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/yEg06y8.jpg

Answer (score 1):

As you got its solution already i am posting a answer here with just a thought that it will help others. You might be not able to post a answer for your own question.

You are using a **Webshop Matrix rate** extension for a shipping method. They provide a facility to set a rate for different courier in **Delivery Type**  column so to achieve this you need to make use of this column as follows.

[image]

which will help you to show two different courier at checkout page.

Hope this will help others.

Comment: shall i import using MAGMI

Comment: bro, i get 2 same courier rates

Comment: How can i solve it,

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/zrvw3Pv.png

Comment: Is possible can i enter weight as KG in webshopapps metrix rate, because Default UPS, FEDEX, DHL required products weight as KG, but i am using Grams for webshopapps metrix rate. Is possible can i use products weight as KG in webshopapps metrix rate.